# Formula to count out of work hours in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to work out the out of hours that someone was at work. So, if it's a weekday and it's not between 8am-6pm, then the answer would be "yes" and if it's a Saturday or Sunday, the answer would be "yes".

There are 3 columns:
1. Date (A)
2. Time (B)
3. Out of Hours (C)

I've copied in the formula below which is printing out "no" for all of the rows but there are rows that should be "yes" for people who have been at work outside of the work hours.

**=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A1)>1,WEEKDAY(A2)<7),"No",IF(AND(B2>=8/24,B2<18/24),"No","Yes"))**

If anyone could advise where I am going wrong, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is hitting a TRUE clause on the first argument which is making it not proceed to the second argument:

`=IF(Arugment1,TRUE["No"],FALSE[Argument2,TRUE["No"],FALSE["Yes"]])`

```
=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A1)>1,WEEKDAY(A2)<7),  'If weekday is between 1 & 7
"No",                                  'Then return "No", as long as it is a weekday it will always return no without going any further!
IF(AND(B2>=8/24,B2<18/24),
    "No",
    "Yes"))
```

You will want to reverse the initial check:

`=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A1)=1,WEEKDAY(A1)=7),"Yes",IF(AND(B2>=8/24,B2<18/24),"No","Yes"))`

Now the second if statement will be checked only when it is a weekday to then check the hours. I would use something like `TIMEVALUE()` function for the second if but depends how your value is formatted.